# retrieve checkboxlist selection from database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist which when submitted stores the selections in a table with the userid.The table is shown below :

```
    Create table tblInterestByUserId
     (
     Id int primary key identity,
     UserId varchar(10),
     SubInterestId int,
     SubInterest varchar(20),
     InterestId int
      )
```

Now i want to retrieve the selection on another checkboxlist on another page depending upon SubInterestId.I want to do something like this on the new page :

1.Going through all inserted SubInterest rows in tblInterestByUserId for the selected UserId.
2.Populating the checkboxlist according to the SubIinterest already present in tblInterestByUserId for that UserId

Please help me with a code-behind for the same on Page_Load.

Comment: With a select statement perhaps?

Comment: I know i have to use a select statement.I am confused about using a Read loop or maybe something else? I need a start.

Comment: and why are you keeping the `SubInterest varchar(20)` in this table? it should be in a different table, and in this table only have it's id

Comment: It is for a different purpose.There cannot be any other table.Disregard the other columns.The only ones of concern are UserId and SubInterestId

Comment: yes you can use Read loop

Comment: There is no need to loop to pull data like this. I agree that SubInterestID and SubInterest is an indication that this not normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a procedure to get the data you want....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_selections 
 @SubInterestId INT 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT SubInterest FROM tblInterestByUserId
   WHERE SubInterestId = @SubInterestId
END
```

Call this procedure from the application code

Comment: Code-Behind? I mean thats where i am completely blank.I could have done this with a simple select statement too.

Comment: So your problem is not with the SQL, it's with the ASP.Net.
Please describe your problem better so that people will not have to waist time answering the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion is tu use an enum with Flags in C# that maps with the subinterestID so then you can select the stored Ids and assign them to the enum. 
see this:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1646982.aspx?enums+and+checkboxlist

Comment: enums are a bad option for dynamic data. unless you think that changing the code for each subInterest added or removed from the system is a good idea

Comment: Yes You are right, this approach is used mostly for static checkbox lists